# Metro App Certification hangs on performance test because of byte code generation

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I try to build a metro-style-app with Javascript and when I run the Windows App Cert Kit (WACK) Certification tool the test always fails on the performance test with the following message:

> **Following errors were detected when tested the byte code generation:**
>   This package was made available for the development or Authoringmodus. Uninstall the package and reinstall it in the normal way.

I’m using jquery and some jquery-mobile libraries inside my app. Is that the problem? The error doesn’t make sense for me, because it doesn’t say which package I should reinstall. I also try to uninstall the App itself (by right click onto the app) and build it again in the Release-Modus of VS2012, but the WACK tool always prompts this error :(

Comment: Are you trying to migrate code from DP or CP to RP?  That is, was this solution created on DP or CP?

Comment: I'am using the german version of RP. The solution was created on RP. I just translated the error from German to English. Maybe I have to check, what the english WACK-Tool shows.

Comment: The strange thing is, even when I create a new Project and compile it and run the WACK test, this error apears too. I even reinstallt the VM to test it on a new Win 8 RP -> still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out that the WACK Tool allways shows this error if you don't run Store -> Create App Package and select "No" and press the next button. After that the WACK-Tool is started automatically and it passes the bytecode generation.

Answer (score 0):

First save the all javascript files with encoding utf 8 format with signature [image]
then create the app package 
     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh975357.aspx

then if u already install the latest windows app certification kit then u will be able to see run with windows app certification kit button after creating app package .